# How to fix that at filtering an multidimensional array, the array gets more elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array called "*Places*" like this:

```
0: Array [ 1, 1 ]
1: Array [ 1, 2 ]
2: Array [ 1, 3 ]
3: Array [ 1, 4 ]
4: Array [ 1, 5 ]
5: Array [ 2, 1 ]
6: Array [ 2, 2 ]
7: Array [ 2, 3 ]
8: Array [ 2, 4 ]
9: Array [ 2, 5 ]
10: Array [ 3, 1 ]
11: Array [ 3, 2 ]
12: Array [ 3, 3 ]
13: Array [ 3, 4 ]

and so on until [ 5, 5 ]
```

I have also another array (called "*occupied*"):

```
0: Array [ 1, 5 ]
```

And I have a for-in loop that creates an new array ("*unOccupied*") with all the things in "*Places*" except the things that are also in "*occupied*".
This is the code:

```
for(var arr in Places){
    for(var filtered in occupied){
        if(Places[arr][0] !== occupied[filtered][0] || Places[arr][1] !== occupied[filtered][1]){
            unOccupied.push(Places[arr]);
        }
    }
}
```

What I expected, is that unOccupied becames something like this:

```
0: Array [ 1, 1 ]
1: Array [ 1, 2 ]
2: Array [ 1, 3 ]
3: Array [ 1, 4 ]
4: Array [ 2, 1 ]
5: Array [ 2, 2 ]

and so on until [ 5, 5 ]
```

So, this is a copy of "*Places*", but without the elements of "*occupied*".

If "*occupied*" contains 1 element, everything works well, and "*unOccupied*" contains 24 elements. But if "*occupied*" contains for example 2 elements, "*unOccupied*" does have 48 elements, and everything that "*Places*" haves, is double, except the elements that are also in "*occupied*".

If "*occupied*" contains more elements, "*unOccupied*" contains also much more elements. But why? And how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `What I expected` ... please show what you get as well (don't just describe it, show it)... or make your code into a runnable snippet

Comment: Okay, but how to make a snippet? (Sorry I'm new here)

Comment: I suppose you need a better data structure for efficiency. How about placing all sub arrays starting with 1 at index 1 with a sub array value like `[null,1,2,3,4,5]` so that you can access the 2D space directly by `arr[n][m]` and nullify tha value if occupied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is incomplete:

What is happening?

```
for(var arr in Places){
    for(var filtered in occupied){
        if(Places[arr][0] !== occupied[filtered][0] || Places[arr][1] !== occupied[filtered][1]){
            unOccupied.push(Places[arr]);
        }
    }
}
```

It works well with only one element in `occupied` due to it only iterates one time over the current place `arr`. when you have more items in `occupied` you iterate n-times over the same place `arr` inserting it n-times if the condition is valid.

So you need to define when a place must be added to `unoccupied` this is when a place is not in `occupied`.

```
for(var arr in Places){
  let isOccupied = false;
  for(var filtered in occupied){      
      if(Places[arr][0] === occupied[filtered][0] || Places[arr][1] === occupied[filtered][1]){
          isOccupied = true;
          break;
      }      
  }
  !isOccupied && unOccupied.push(Places[arr]);
}
```

Also you can improve this by:

```
const unoccupied = Places.filter(place => occupied.every(occ => occ[0] !== place[0] || occ[1] !== place[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
 for(var filtered in occupied)
```

If you have `3` elements in `occupied` there will be `72` elements in the `unOccupied` array. Reason:

Say you have

```
places  = [1, 2]
occupied = [1, 1], [1, 4], [1, 3]
```

Now, this loop will run `3` times:

```
for(var filtered in occupied){
    if(Places[arr][0] !== occupied[filtered][0] || Places[arr][1] !== occupied[filtered][1]){
        unOccupied.push(Places[arr]);
    }
```

and, every time you are saving same elements in the `unOccupied` array. So, `unOccupied` array will become:

```
unOccupied = [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]
```

You can do something like this:

```
var count = 0;
for(var arr in Places){
    for(var filtered in occupied){
        if(Places[arr][0] !== occupied[filtered][0] || Places[arr][1] !== occupied[filtered][1]){
            count++;
        }
        if(count === occupied.length)
            unOccupied.push(Places[arr]);
    }
}
```